# performBlockAndWait vs dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()

Tags: ios, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

```
Utility.managedObjectContext().performBlockAndWait({

})

dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

})
```

1. Curious what is the difference between the two code above? context was created with `.MainQueueConcurrencyType` option.
2. If I perform blocks on the main queue, are queues executed in a FIFO order? Or can they overlap, operation mingle? I.e. (a1,a2,a3),(b1,b2,b3) can result (a1,b1,a2,a3,b2,b3)?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two entirely different concepts here, but since it is the main thread/context/queue, your mix is masked and it "works".

Managed object context's `performBlockAndWait:` and `performBlock:` methods do not make any guarantees on which thread the block is executed, only that data accessed/mutated is safely accessed. Since your context is of main queue concurrency type, it is the exception in that it is safe to touch its objects outside of the `performBlockAndWait:` and `performBlock:` methods, on the main thread only. So when you queue your block to run on the main queue, it is guaranteed to run on the main thread, and thus your data is safe.

Block execution on the main thread is not atomic. Otherwise, what is the point of multithreading? To ensure data safety, you must `performBlockAndWait:` and `performBlock:` methods are called when accessing data. You are guaranteed that main queue scheduled blocks will run uninterrupted by other main queue scheduled blocks, and managed object context queues (background or main) are serial, so only one block will be allowed to concurrently access data.

Comment: usually saving context goes with other things together like this: (1) cleaning indexPath containers (2) save context (3) `NSFetchedResultedController` callback will get called (4) indexPath containers will filled up (5) insert / delete rows in tableView (6) cleaning indexPath containers again - because I need these whole code in a critical section you say: do not simply dispatch it on the main queue with `dispatch_sync`, but use `performBlockAndWait`, am I understand right?

Comment: It is preferred, yes. Remember not to update UI from that block. Sicne you have a fetched results controller, and it is tied to a main queue managed object context, it will guarantee being called on the main thread, so it will be safe to update UI there.